# Why the single.php in wordpress theme, every page display the same content?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<div class="content" style="min-height:1022px;"> 
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="singlepost">
<h1 class="page-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>    </h1>
<div class="post_info">
<p><?php the_time('Y年n月j日') ?>
<span>/ </span>
<?php comments_popup_link('0 comment', '1 comment', '% comments', '', 'closed'); ?>
<span>/ </span>
<?php the_category(', ') ?>
</p> 
</div>
<div class="post1">
<div class="post1text">
<!-- Post Content -->
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
</div>   
<p class="clearfix" style="margin-left:20px;"><?php previous_posts_link('&lt;&lt; TheNewer', 0); ?> <span class="float right"><?php next_posts_link('ThePast &gt;&gt;', 0); ?></span></p>
</div>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="cleared"></div>      
</div>
```

Above code is my single.php which display the content, but it's display every page the same content, so, what's wrong with it? is the loop? Thanks very much~

Comment: I don't think is there any problem in loop

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your loop, what happens in the header?

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy once you understand the basic template selection hierarchy, which should get you started.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

You can also create page templates, it's really very simple and useful.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_your_own_Page_Templates

And finally once you have got all that working, you can start doing some really clever stuff with conditional tags.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Instead of your code try this simple code in single.php

```
            <div class="content" style="min-height:1022px;">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <nav id="nav-single">
                    <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                    <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?></span>
                    <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?></span>
                </nav><!-- #nav-single -->

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hope you are using WordPress 3.0 or above version with the child theme of twentyeleven.